# What is the number in parentheses randomly changing on my chrome tab?

Tags: support

What is the number in parentheses randomly changing on my chrome tab?

My chrome tab reads "(1) Physics Stack Exchange"

Then a few minutes later is reads...

My chrome tab reads "(2) Physics Stack Exchange"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the number of questions with new activity since you last refreshed the page. If you click over to that tab, the top of the questions list will have a gray box with the message "1 question with new activity."